# gdb error message: DW_OP_reg, DW_OP_piece, and DW_OP_bit_piece

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, gdb

I'm debugging somebody else's Qt program and ran into the following error message which I don't understand:

```
DWARF-2 expression error: DW_OP_reg operations must be used either alone or in
conjuction with DW_OP_piece or DW_OP_bit_piece.
```

I'm not sure what that means and Google isn't of much help.

Here's the context - `sLocation` is a `QString` that was declared a few lines earlier. However, it was created from functions which were inlined, so I'm not sure of its value and am attempting to check before being appended to:

```
(gdb) printqstring suffix
(QString)0xffffbd80: "sorted"
(gdb) next
1241        sLocation += suffix;
(gdb) printqstring sLocation
Can't take address of "sLocation" which isn't an lvalue.
(gdb) info local
sLocation = <error reading variable sLocation (DWARF-2 expression error:
    DW_OP_reg operations must be used either alone or in conjuction with
    DW_OP_piece or DW_OP_bit_piece.)>
```

Could somebody please explain what that error message means or what could cause it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message means that `GDB` is reading `DWARF2` debug info from the executable, and is rejecting that info as invalid (not following the `DWARF2` standard).

The invalid info is likely due to a bug in GCC, fixed in SVN revision 147187:

```
2009-05-06  Jakub Jelinek  <jakub@redhat.com>

    * dwarf2out.c (new_reg_loc_descr): Don't ever create DW_OP_regX.
    (one_reg_loc_descriptor): Create DW_OP_regX here instead of calling
    new_reg_loc_descr.
    (loc_by_reference): If loc is DW_OP_regX, change it into DW_OP_bregX 0
    instead of appending DW_OP_deref*.
```

Comment: With the help of somebody on IRC I was able to use `readelf -wi /path/to/debug/lib` to identify the offending entry: `2 byte block: 53 6 (DW_OP_reg3; DW_OP_deref).` However, I'm using gcc-4.4.4 which was tagged in r158895, so I think this may be a new or related bug.

Comment: I see the same error on `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian` with `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem running a Ubuntu 10.10 64bit. However, the same code on a 10.04 LTS 32bit works perfectly.

Here is the version output of both setups
Ubuntu 10.10:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

GCC on 10.04 LTS:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5
```

Cheers,
Andre